# When were the Greek names for these countries first used?

Tags: etymology, greek

I'm analyzing this [Greek prophecy](https://byzantineprophecy.com/2020/05/10/the-anonymous-prophecy-of-1053-ad/) which is contested to be from 1053 or 1753. I've seen [claims](https://byzantineprophecy.com/2023/09/06/is-saint-kosmas-the-aetolian-the-author-of-the-anonymous-prophecy-of-1053-ad/) that it uses Greek words anachronistic to 1053:

> Now over the years I began to doubt if the dating of the prophecy to 1053 AD, just one year after the Great Schism, was accurate, as there is some language there on the names of nations that did not even exist at that time, like Germany and Austria, that would date the prophecy much later than the year 1053 AD. The short name for “Austria” was not used into the 12th Century. The word “German” was not even used before the year 1520.

As well as [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/byzantium/comments/ixb53t/byzantine_prophecies/):

> Talks about Orthodox faith a year before the Schism (which was not considered permanent at the time), talks about Helenes ( which was not how they called themselves) and about Russia and Austria which of course did not exist back then.

The text uses the following relevant terms:

- `Γερμανίας` and `Γερμανών` for Germany and Germans respectively.
- `Ρωσσίας` for Russia.
- `Αὐστρίας` for Austria.
- `Αγαρ` for Hagar, which might be in reference to Turkey but I'm not sure.
- `Ελλήνων` for Greeks.
- `Ορθοδόξων` for Orthodox.

My question is: when were these words first used in Greek? Are any anachronistic to 1053 and/or 1753? Where can I look this kind of thing up? I need to source this for my analysis.

Here is my best effort at transcribing the full original text if it's relevant:

> Μέγας Εὐρωπαϊκός πόλεμος. 'Ηττα τῆς Γερμανίας καί καταστροφή Ρωσσίας καί Αὐστρίας. 'Ηττα Αγαρ ὑπό Ελλήνων. Ἑνίσχυσις ̓Αγαρ ὑπό Δυτικῶν λαῶν καί ἧττα τῶν Ἑλλήνων ὑπό Αγαρ. Σφαγή 'Ορθοδόξων λαῶν kαί μεγάλη ἀνησυχία 'Ορθοδόξων λαῶν. Εἰσβολή ξένων στρατευμάτων ἐξ ̓Αδριατικού πελάγους. Οὐαί εἰς τούς κατοικοῦντας ἐπί τῆς γῆς, ὁ ἅδης ἔτοιμος. Προς στιγμήν Αγαρ μέγας. Νέος ευρωπαϊκός πόλεμος. "Ενωσις 'Ορθοδόξων λαῶν μετά τῆς Γερμανίας. 'Ηττα Γάλλων ὑπό Γερμανών. Ἐπανάστασις τῶν Ἰνδιῶν καί χωρισμός αὐτῶν ἀπό τῆς ̓Αγγλίας.  ̓Αγγλία εἰς μόνους Σάξωνας. Νίκη 'Ορθοδόξων. Ηττα Αγαρ καί γενική σφαγή Αγαρ ὑπό Ορθοδόξων λαῶν.  ̓Ανησυχία κόσμου καί Γενική ἀπελπισία ἐπί τῆς γῆς. Μάχη ἑπτά κρατῶν εἰς Κωνσταντινούπολιν. Τρία ἡμερονύκτια σφαγή καί nίκη τοῦ μεγαλυτέρου κράτους κατά τῶν ἕξ κρατῶν. Συμμαχία ἓξ κρατῶν κατὰ τοῦ ἑβδόμου κράτους, τρία ἡμερονύκτια σφαγή. Παῦσις πολέμου ὑπό ἀγγέλου καί παράδοσις πόλεως τοῖς Ελλησι. 'Υπόκυψις Λατίνων εἰς ἀλάνθαστον Πίστιν Ορθοδόξων. Ἐξωθήσεται Ορθόδοξος Πίστις από ̓Ανατολῶν μέχρι Δυσμῶν. Φόβος καί τρόμος βαρβάρων ὑπ' αὐτῆς. Παῦσις τοῦ Πάπα καὶ κήρυξις ἑνός Πατριάρχου δι ̓ ὅλην τήν Εὐρώπην. Ἐν πέντε καί πεντήκοντα ἔτη τό τέλος τῶν θλίψεων· τήν δέ ἑβδόμην οὐκ ἔστι ταλαίπωρος, οὐκ ἔστι ἐξόριστος. ἐπανερχόμενος εἰς τάς ἀγκάλας τῆς Μητρός ἀγαλλομένης Οὕτως ἔσται καί οὕτω γένοιτο.

Comment: The term Ρωσσίας is definitely anachronistic for 1053. The term was introduced by Peter the Great in the 18th century.

Comment: @Anixx thanks for the info! Do you have a source I could reference?

Comment: @Anixx - Vasmer doesn't agree with you: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/Россия#Этимология

Comment: The double sigma seems anachronistic for the 1000s.  *Далее из русск.-цслав. Рѡсїа (впервые в выходной записи южного славянина митрополита Киприана в 1387 в сочетании всеѧ Рѡсїѧ, совр. русск.-цслав. Рѡссіа), из ср.-греч. Ῥωσία ‘страна росов; Русь; Русская митрополия’ (с X в., ср. нов.-гр. Ρωσία, Ρωσσία, Ρουσία, Ρουσσία ‘Россия’), от ср.-греч.*